# How do I set `state_selected` in a layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a xml drawable like this:

```
<selector>
  <item android:state_selected="true">
    ...
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  <item>
</selector>
```

and then I set this drawable as background to my view. But the only default state is visible. At a runtime selected state behaves strange so I'd like to see it in preview while editing my layout.
I though I can set `tools:state="selected"` or `tools:selected="true"` but it turned out this is not possible.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided which shape or drawable need to be set when state is selected.

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image"/>
</selector>
```

You can also add shape in this way.

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

After that set this drawabl
e as background of your view.

Comment: Thsnks for your ansver, but this is not what I've been asking. I fact I've provided all the drawables and set correctly. Just skipped it here as it works well. I've been asking about viewing different states in preview. It shows default state, but I'd like to see other states in preview